# varnish unsetting X-Forwarded-For

Tags: varnish

I am running varnish-4.0.4-3 on centos7.

In the varnish logs, I find:

```
23 ReqUnset       c X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.1.2
23 ReqHeader      c X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.1.2, 127.0.0.1
```

How can I disable `X-Forwarded-For` modification please?

Answer (score 1):

While it does unset it on the first line of your varnishlog, it sets it *back* on the second line and appends `client.ip`. This is default new behaviour in Varnish 4.

See [here](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/4.0/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_req_fsm.c#L724)